# I have cloned git repo and after doing composer install I am getting these two errors?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, windows, dll

Earlier the project was on laravel 7  and now they have upgraded to laravel 9 now, so after doin git pull  I ran composer install and got these two errors:

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser ^8.0 -> satisfiable by php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser[8.0.0].
- php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser 8.0.0 requires ext-mailparse * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mailparse extension.

Problem 2
- mongodb/mongodb dev-master requires ext-mongodb ^1.16.0 -> it has the wrong version installed (1.13.0).
- mongodb/mongodb[1.15.0, ..., v1.15.x-dev] require ext-mongodb ^1.15.0 -> it has the wrong version installed (1.13.0).
- mongodb/mongodb 1.16.x-dev is an alias of mongodb/mongodb dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
- Root composer.json requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.15 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.15.0, v1.15.x-dev, 1.16.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-mailparse --ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

I am running this on my windows machine so here we have .dll files which we need to install in our system , but for mail parser the latest .dll is [https://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) this and for mongodB is : [https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), so how can I install 1.151 mongodB extension and 8.0.0 extension for mailparse. Please help me out with this as I am stuck into this since last 4 days.

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: What are you using for your local server (XAMPP, WampServer, MAMP, something else)? Did you change your `php.ini`, so that the extensions are enabled? If you did that, did you restart your server?

Comment: I am using Xampp as local server on my windows machine.

Comment: I am using php version 8.1, the one which comes with xampp only

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are using the correct PHP version as required in laravel 9. Laravel 9 needed Php 8.